# Selecting element from VBA union

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task to make a VBA macro based on few sections in .xls file.
I know that in this file it will always be three sections which starts with specific name in example file "Block". But starting row where "Block" is written each time could be different.

Example of .xls file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh1e1.png)

My approach had been to search for address of each column containing string "Block"
And later make further code based on knowing there start of each block are.
My code so far:

```
Public Values

Sub Macro1()

FindAll ("Block")
Debug.Print Values
'    
End Sub

Sub FindAll(text)

Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

  fnd = text

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

'Test to see if anything was found
  If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
  Else
    GoTo NothingFound
  End If

Set rng = FoundCell

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
  Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    'Find next cell with fnd value
      Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
    
    'Add found cell to rng range variable
      Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
    
    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
      If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
      
  Loop

'Creates global value with all found adresses
  Values = rng.Address
 
Exit Sub
```

Output Is received as intended:

```
$A$5,$A$8,$A$1
```

However I struggle to select element for further coding.
I tried:

```
Debug.Print Values.Rows.item(1).Adress
Debug.Print Values.Rows.item(1,1).Adress
Debug.Print Values.Rows.item(1)
Debug.Print Values.Rows.item(1,1)
```

But it yields "Run-time error '424' "

My desired output would be to create three variables containing addresses for these sections.
That

```
Debug.Print Section_1
Debug.Print Section_2
Debug.Print Section_3
```

Would yield:

```
$A$1
$A$5
$A$8
```

Is there a way to select nth element from union in VBA?

Comment: If you have the range as a delimited string, you can use `SPLIT` to generate an array of the addresses which can then be accessed by index

Comment: Instead of `Value`, here are some examples how to continue: `Debug.Print rng.Areas.Count` or: `Debug.Print rng.Areas(1).Address` or: `For Each arg In rng.Areas: Debug.Print arg.Address: Next arg`

Comment: You've got the line `GoTo NothingFound` but no label called `NothingFound`.  I'd put the whole Found loop within the If statement to avoid the GoTo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the single cells of the range, you can simply loop over it:

```
Dim cell as Range
For Each cell In rng
    Debug.Print cell.Address
Next
```

Could also be done using an index:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To rng.Count
    Debug.Print rng(i).Address
Next
```

Now in your example, you combine single cells using Union. If you combine larger ranges and want to access those ranges, you can use the `Areas`-Property. However, Excel will optimize the areas, if you do `Union(Range("A1"), Range("A2))`, you will end up with *one* area `A1:A2`.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = Union(.Range("D5:E16"), .Range("A1:F12"), .Range("X4"))
End With

Dim a As Range
For Each a In rng.Areas
    Debug.Print a.Address
Next

For i = 1 to rng.Areas.Count
    Debug.Print rng(i).Address
Next
```

Btw: Every Range (even a single cell) has the `Areas`-property set, so it's always safe to loop over the `Areas` of a range.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Public Values
Public rngDB() As Range
Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Integer
    FindAll ("Block")
    Debug.Print Values
    
    For i = LBound(rngDB) To UBound(rngDB)
       Debug.Print rngDB(i).Address
       Debug.Print rngDB(i).Cells(1).Address
       Debug.Print rngDB(i).Cells(1, 2).Address
       Debug.Print rngDB(i).Cells(2, 1).Address
    Next i
End Sub

Sub FindAll(text)

    Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
    Dim sAddress() As String
    Dim n As Integer
    
    fnd = text
    
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
    Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)
    
    'Test to see if anything was found
      If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
      Else
        'GoTo NothingFound
      End If
    
    Set rng = FoundCell
    
    'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
        Do
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve rngDB(1 To n)
            ReDim Preserve sAddress(1 To n)
            Set rngDB(n) = FoundCell.CurrentRegion
            sAddress(n) = rngDB(n).Address
            Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        
        Loop While FoundCell.Address <> FirstFound
    
    'Creates global value with all found adresses
    If n Then
        Values = Join(sAddress, ",")
    End If
 
End Sub
```